# mysql query extract multiple records with one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is my table

```
id | question |
```

id's are grouped as

```
1000 -> 1050
2000 -> 2030
3000 -> 3099
4000 -> 4500
5000 -> 5010
```

I have to extract 5 records and one for each group of id.

How can I perform this with only one query?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you give sample records on this?

Comment: The easiest solution: Five queries, each of them selecting one (random?) value from one of the given ranges, and making them into one result set via `UNION`.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, so there is any possibility to do it with only one query?

Comment: @Vyktor it's not a duplicated question!

Comment: @michele In which way is it not a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f1, f2, ... FROM tablename WHERE id BETWEEN 1000 AND 1050 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECTS f1, f2, ... FROM tablename WHERE id BETWEEN 2000 AND 2030 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECTS f1, f2, ... FROM tablename WHERE id BETWEEN 2000 AND 2030 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

and two more selects with UNION

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, IF (id > 1000 AND id < 1050, 1, 
          IF (id > 2000 AND id < 2030, 2,
          IF (id > 3000 AND id < 3099, 3,
          IF (id > 4000 AND id < 4500, 4,
          IF (id > 5000 AND id < 5010, 5, 0))))) AS param 
FROM questions WHERE param > 0 GROUP BY param
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this with just one query (without using `UNION` as was suggested by [NedretRecap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880146/1149736)), you can  add `group_id` (or similar column) to your table and use simple `... GROUP BY group_id`.

Assuming that the *reserved group size* is **always** the same (it's not possible that some groups will start at `+1000` from previous, and other at `+300`) you could probably use this simple hack:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
GROUP BY FLOOR(id/1000)
```

Working example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17a44/3/0).